# change visibility of label tag using jquery

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a label with hidden visibility on page load. How can i make it visible using jquery

```
<label for="error" style="margin:100px auto 60px auto;color:Red; line-height:40px;font-size:medium;visibility:hidden">error occured</label>
```

I am able to hide it.

```
  $('label[for="error"]').hide();
```

This doesn't work

```
 $('label[for="error"]').show();
```

Comment: Just guessing, but try display: none; instead of visibility: hidden;

Comment: When you say hidden visibility, do you mean `display:none`?

Comment: That or it's possible it is showing but is hidden behind something else.

Comment: changing visibility:hidden to display:none fixes your problem.....http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

Comment: If it is visibility:hidden, and you want to maintain position, set opacity to 0

Comment: hide() and show() change if you can see an element by adding display:none; and then removing display:none; don't use visibility to hide things........

Comment: Thank you all.  visibility: hidden was was my problem.   display:none fixed my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your code as follows:

```
<label for="error" style="margin:100px auto 60px auto;color:Red; line-height:40px;font-size:medium;display:none">error occured</label>
```

I've replaced your `visibility:hidden` with `display:none`.

You can then use the jQuery **hide()** and **show()** functions.

Answer (score 4):

Set the CSS property [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) to `visible`.

```
$('label[for="error"]').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

`Visibility:hidden` and `display:none` both are the different things:

You can check it's difference [Play](http://fiddle.jshell.net/H2v3f/1/)

You are hiding your element with

`visibility:hidden`

try `display:none` instead `visibility: hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Your css has "visibility:hidden", which is responsible for hiding the labels, not the jquery method.  Use "display:none" instead

Answer (score 0):

Try to use display:none instead of visibility:hidden
I've made a jsFiddle for you.

```
label[for="error"]{
    margin:100px auto 60px auto;
    color:Red; 
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:medium;
    display:none;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pghy3/